# Fixing width and other CSS problems in menu navigation

Tags: html, css, menu

I am coding a very simple CSS navigation menu. I’m trying to stretch the `nav` to 100% width across the page and set the last menu option to orange background color and white text color to no avail.

Can someone have a look at my CSS code and see where my problem is?

```css
body {
  background: #282828;
}
#nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#nav ul li {
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  background-color: #282c2b;
  color: #fff;
}
#nav > ul > li {
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: #282c2b;
  border-left: 4px solid #282c2b;
}
#nav li > ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  color: #fff;
}
#nav > ul > li > ul {
  width: 100%;
  top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  left: -4px;
}
#nav li:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #282c2b;
  border-left: 4px solid #ff3d00;
}
#nav li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
#nav ul li .navOrange {
  background-color: #ff3d00;
}
```

Here’s a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJjWgV)

I know it might be hard to achieve this with pure CSS but is it possible to make the menu drop down upon clicking or is it just set to rollover without JavaScript?

so i decided to change it up a little and use  elements because it suits me better.

so i now have the following;

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waKENz

when i add  around the div elements it doesnt use the style setup in css, why is it doing this?

and is it possible to perhaps have menu option 4 perform a dropdown on rollover as before or not with  elements.

Comment: Include your HTML also please. How do you want your navigation to appear when it is full width? Do you want each button to stretch out? Or do you want the gaps between the buttons to expand? You will need JS for the menu item to be clicked and remain visible. If you just want the dropdown to show on hover, that can be done with CSS.

Comment: Each button to stretch out will be fine, Gaps to stay very similar. Also wanted to try and add gaps on the drop downs to match if possible but not important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to target each navigation item seperately by setting a percentage width for the item and probably a percentage margin also. Make sure they all add up to 100%.

```css
#nav > ul > li {
    margin: 0 1%;
}
.home,
.level-1,
.support,
.sign-up {
    width: 18%;
}
.info {
    width: 20%;
}
.home {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.sign-up {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="home">Home</li>
        <li class="info">Information</li>
        <li class="level-1">Level 1</li>
        <li class="support">Support</li>
        <li class="sign-up">SIGN-UP!</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here's a demo [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tqdrz1qx/) (not full code).

The last item in the navigation is not turning orange because the selector is incorrect. You have:

```css
#nav ul li .navOrange { background-color: #ff3d00;}
```

Which says (working right to left), select  **any** element with the class of `.navOrange` that is a **child** of any `li` that is a **child** of any `ul` that is a **child** of `#nav`. `.navOrange` is an **not a child** of an `li` but on class on an `li` and also a child of a `ul`.

Remove `li` from the selector and it will work.

```css
#nav ul .navOrange { background-color: #ff3d00;}
```

Answer (score 0):

About the orange background color: you need to remove the space between "li" and ".navOrange" in the last definition. This will make it more specific than the other definitions and be applied later.

Full width can be achieved relatively simply if you know how many options you'll have in the menu with resizing the buttons to an adequate percentage. Though be careful with this - you generally want something less than 20% with 5 buttons because of the margins etc.

The hover menu that you already have is pure CSS, I don't know of a way to make it onclick without JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code snippet.

```css
body {background: #282828;}
#nav ul{ margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; }
#nav ul li{ margin-right:5px; padding:10px 20px; position:relative; height:20px; line-height:20px; background-color:#282c2b; color:#fff; }
#nav > ul > li { float: left; height:30px; line-height:30px; background-color:#282c2b; border-left:4px solid #282c2b; }
#nav li > ul{ visibility:hidden; position: absolute; top:70px; color:#fff;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  opacity: 0;
}
#nav li.have-item:hover ul{
  visibility:visible;
  top:50px;
  opacity: 1;
}
#nav > ul > li > ul{ width:100%; margin-bottom:10px; left:-4px; }
#nav > ul > li > ul li{
  width:100%;
}
#nav li:hover{ background-color:#ffffff; color:#282c2b; border-left:4px solid #ff3d00;  }
#nav li:hover > ul{visibility:visible;}
#nav > ul > li:last-child { background-color:#ff3d00 !important; }
```

```html
<div id="nav">
 <ul>
     <li>Home</li>
        
        <li>Information</li>
        
        <li>Level 1</li>
        
        <li class="have-item">Support
         <ul>
             <li>FAQ</li>
             <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        
        <li class="navOrange">SIGN-UP!</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```